# Optimizing a MySQL query on big tables

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a SQL query with 3 tables joined on a distant MySQL DB- Two of these tables have size of about 18GByte (STEP_RESULT and meas_numericlimit) and then the distant server create a TMP table which takes age (about 25 min) to end
How can I optimize this query ?

```
select 
    t1.UUT_NAME, 
    t1.STATION_NUM, 
    t1.START_DATE_TIME, 
    t3.LOW_LIMIT, 
    t3.DATA,
    t3.HIGH_LIMIT,
    t3.UNITS,
    t2b.STEP_NAME 
from 
    meas_numericlimit t3 
        inner join STEP_RESULT t2a on t3.ID = t2a.STEP_ID
        inner join STEP_RESULT t2b on t2a.STEP_PARENT = t2b.STEP_ID
        inner join uut_result t1 on t2b.UUT_RESULT = t1.ID
where 
    t1.UUT_NAME like 'Variable1-1%' and 
    t1.STATION_NUM = 'variable2' and 
    t2b.STEP_NAME = 'variable3' and 
    t2b.STEP_TYPE = 'constant'
```

Here the SHOW TABLES and EXPLAIN output queries :

```
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_spectrum |
+--------------------+
| cal_dates          |
| calibrage          |
| execution_time     |
| meas_numericlimit  |
| station_feature    |
| step_callexe       |
| step_graph         |
| step_msgjnl        |
| step_msgpopup      |
| step_passfail      |
| step_result        |
| step_seqcall       |
| step_stringvalue   |
| syst_event         |
| uptime             |
| users              |
| uut_result         |
+--------------------+
```

and

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+---------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys           | key     | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+---------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2a   | ALL    | NULL                    | NULL    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2b   | ALL    | NULL                    | NULL    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK_uut_result_1 | PRIMARY |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+---------+

---------+----------------------+----------- +---------------------------+
key_len  | ref                  |    rows    | Extra                     |
---------+----------------------+----------- +---------------------------+
 NULL    | NULL                 | 48120004   |                           |
 40      | spectrum.t2a.STEP_ID |        1   |                           |
 NULL    | NULL                 | 48120004   | Using where; Using join
                                                                 buffer  |
 40      | spectrum.t2b.UUT_RESULT |       1 | Using where               |
  -------+----------------------+------------+---------------------------+
```

Here the SHOW CREATE TABLE :

```
CREATE TABLE `uut_result` (
    `ID` varchar(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `STATION_NUM` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `SOFTVER_ODTGEN` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `HARDVER_ODTGEN` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `NEXT_CAL_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL, 
    `UUT_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `UUT_SERIAL_NUMBER` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `UUT_VERSION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `USER_LOGIN_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `USER_LOGIN_LOGIN` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `START_DATE_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    `EXECUTION_TIME` float DEFAULT NULL, 
    `UUT_STATUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `UUT_ERROR_CODE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `UUT_ERROR_MESSAGE` varchar(1023) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `PAT_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `PAT_VERSION` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `TEST_LEVEL` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `INTERFACE_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `EXECUTION_MODE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `LOOP_MODE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `STOP_ON_FAIL` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `EXECUTION_COMMENT` text, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
    KEY `FK_uut_result_1` (`STATION_NUM`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `meas_numericlimit` (
    `ID` varchar(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `STEP_RESULT` varchar(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `COMP_OPERATOR` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `HIGH_LIMIT` double DEFAULT NULL, 
    `LOW_LIMIT` double DEFAULT NULL, 
    `UNITS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `DATA` double DEFAULT NULL, 
    `STATUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `FORMAT` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `NANDATA` int(11) DEFAULT '0', 
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
    KEY `FK_meas_numericlimit_1` (`STEP_RESULT`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `step_result` (
    `ID` varchar(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `UUT_RESULT` varchar(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `STEP_PARENT` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `STEP_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `STEP_ID` varchar(38) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `STEP_TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `STATUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `REPORT_TEXT` text, 
    `DIAG` text, 
    `ERROR_OCCURRED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `ERROR_CODE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ERROR_MESSAGE` varchar(1023) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `MODULE_TIME` float DEFAULT NULL, 
    `TOTAL_TIME` float DEFAULT NULL, 
    `NUM_LOOPS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `NUM_PASSED` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `NUM_FAILED` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ENDING_LOOP_INDEX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `LOOP_INDEX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `INTERACTIVE_EXENUM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `STEP_GROUP` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `STEP_INDEX` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ORDER_NUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
    KEY `FK_step_result_1` (`UUT_RESULT`), 
    KEY `IDX_step_parent` (`STEP_PARENT`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry 18 Giga Bytes

Comment: When asking questions about query optimization, always include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in the query, and the output of `EXPLAIN` for the query. We need to know the table definition, its columns, indexes, constraints, etc. Help us help you!

Comment: And please *not* a screenshot. Just the text please, so we can copy it and test in a sandbox.

Comment: Your main problem for slowness is using `like` in where claause

Comment: @Stivan Ok for the like command, I can suppress the second but how to replace like 'variable1' ? I need to find all variable1 like variable1-1%

Comment: I asked very specifically for the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output and the `EXPLAIN` output, and you didn't do it. I'm afraid I have to move on. Good luck!

Comment: Is it possible to replace :                                                                         
    where t1.UUT_NAME like 'Variable1-1%'  by  where t1 
    CONTAINS(UUT_NAME,'Variable1-1') ?

Comment: @trayvoujba - `CONTAINS` is not a MySQL function.  `LIKE '...%'` is effectively means "starts with '...'".  And it is efficient if there is an index.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `join_buffer_size`?  It should not be more than about 1% of RAM.  If it is much bigger, you run the risk of swapping, which is especially bad for performance.

One thing jumps out in the `EXPLAIN`: `NULL | 48120004` saying that this is needed: `INDEX(STEP_ID)`;

However, the `SELECT` and the `EXPLAIN` do not seem to match.  Please double check.

`uut_result` needs `INDEX(station_num, uut_name)` -- in that order; replaces just `(station_num)`.

What is `varchar(38)`?  UUIDs are only 36.  IPv6 needs 39.

UUIDs are terribly inefficient when the data is too big to be cached.  More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Lots of datatypes could (should) be shrunken -- this shrinkage will cut down on I/O, which will speed up queries.  If you provide some sample values for some typical columns, I can give more advice.

For example, `STATUS` is (usually) a small number of distinct values.  That could be represented as a 1-byte `ENUM` or a 1-byte `TINYINT`; but maybe your app has hundreds of different status values?  If so, "normalizing" it may be the better answer.

`DOUBLE` takes 8 bytes; `FLOAT` takes only 4 bytes, but limits precision to only ~7 significant digits -- perhaps that is sufficient?

(Presumably you meant `latin1`, not `latin`?)

Also consider switching to InnoDB.

How much RAM do you have?  How big (GB) are the tables?

Comment: @trayvoujba - For example, I would readily recognize a UUID or IP address.

Comment: "If you provide some sample values for some typical columns, I can give more advice."                                                                                                   - For example step_result.STEP_ID is "{ac47980b-af6a-4e1b-b622-0a82d28d567c}" and same format for step_result.STEP_PARENT,  step_result.UUT_RESULT, uut_result.ID, meas_numericlimit.ID
These columns don't represent  address but are stored and used by the app like unique keys

Comment: Those are "Type 4" uuids, hence _very_ random.  What is the value of `key_buffer_size`?  To avoid being I/O-bound, you may need more than 64GB of RAM and a larger setting for that `VARIABLE`.  Again, shrinking the datatypes would help.  See my link for how to shrink UUIDs to 16 bytes (from 38), but a 4-byte `INT UNSIGNED` would be even smaller (though possibly not practical now).

Comment: Size from 2 of the 3 tables I use in the query is about 18GB - I will collect other info you ask ASAP (I am not the admin for this server)

Comment: In a first try, I plan to use these 2 CREATE INDEX before the main query like you suggested : CREATE INDEX index1 ON step_result(STEP_ID); and CREATE INDEX index2 ON uut_result(STATION_NUM,UUT_NAME); - What do you think about ?

Comment: How did those two indexes work out?  What is the `EXPLAIN` now?  (I suspect it changed.)

Comment: I mean I will have to create  these 2 index so maybe the query will be faster - I don't know exactly how MySQL works with that - I will have a try with that  on monday